# SSIS: Execute Process Task: How to unzip files in server without any softwares installed?

Tags: ssis, etl, unzip, executeprocesstask

I need design a SSIS package to unzip files from a folder in Server.

The problem is there are no softwares like Winzip or Winrar installed on server.

Our IT dept doesn't installation of softwares on server so I am trying to figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET has the [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) class to perform zip/unzip operations for the zip archive format. You could use a [script task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136127(v=sql.120).aspx) to unzip the file using ZipFile.